# Why although my precision for class 1 is very low (0.05), and the recall is 0.92, the Precision Recall plot shows decent results?

Tags: unbalanced-classes, precision-recall

I have trained a classifier I am experimenting on, using a highly imbalanced data set (284,807 transactions and out of them 370 are of class 1) and I get the following results.

```
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       1.00      0.97      0.98     28432
       1       0.05      0.92      0.09        49
```

I use the predict_proba function from sklearn to get the probabilities matrix, and then I use the precision_recall_curve(test_labels, prob[:, 1]) to get the Precision and the Recall for my plot. But the resulting plot I get from pyplot.plot(recall, precision) comes out like this:

[image]

My question is it possible to have those results and still get a Precision Recall Curve looking like that and if yes how is it explained?

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

PR curve plot displays metrics for every possible classification threshold. If you did not resample your data, the optimal threshold will be far from the default 0.5 used by `predict()` or `classification_report()` (which is somewhere in the lower right corner now).

However, PR curve isn't just a nice visualization. Its values can be used for the optimal threshold selection - for example, the best F1 metric:

```
probabilities = model.predict_proba(...)
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(test_labels, probabilities[:, 1])
# Vectorized operation:
f1_scores = 2 * recall * precision / (recall + precision)
best_f1 = np.max(f1_scores)
best_thresh = thresholds[np.argmax(f1_scores)]
best_predictions = (probabilities > best_thresh)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not resample the data so the default threshold is 0.002 which is the probability of randomly selecting a sample from class 1. Since I can get the optimal threshold and f1-score, how can I use those to improve my model? Also what exactly do those optimal values mean?

Comment: PR curve is a parametric one. Each point of it has a respective third dimension (threshold). Find a point with good precision/recall balance and you'll get a good threshold value to compare your predict_proba() result to. You model does not change at all.

Comment: Thank you very much now i understand.